# Iterative promise if error

Tags: node.js, promise

Below I have a function that returns a promise, where `execAsyc` will throw an error if the `arrayItem` is in valid, if it's invalid we move on to the next. Is there a iterative way to do this?

```
function performAction () {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            return execAsync(arrayItem[0])
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return execAsync(arrayItem[1])
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return execAsync(arrayItem[2])
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) should help you out:

```
function performAction() {
    return arrayItem.reduce((prev, item) => {
        return prev.catch(() => execAsync(item))
    }, Promise.reject()) // start out with a rejected promise, so that execAsync is called for the first item in your array
}
```

This function returns a promise, that rejects if `execAsync` failed for all items in the array, or resolves with the result from `execAsync` for the first valid item.